# New Stack Exchange user profile

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page

I was wondering, when is the new Stack Exchange user profile going to be applied on Drupal Answers? Or is there some user setting which I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [**List of communities with base css updates completed**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed).

Sorry. There has been no specific timeline announced *per se,* but they’re knocking out about a couple per week, so I'm sure those changes will come soon enough.